# How to see in debugger name-less variables computed in the middle of the line?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Assume I have such Java / Kotlin code:

```
return a(b())
```

I want to see in debugger the value of `b()` - what is the best was to do this?

Usually I workaround it by "extract variable" refactoring:

```
var c = b()
// set breakpoint on the next line and variable c is visible in debugger
return b(c)
```

But I would prefer not to modify source code (this pollutes changes log also I can commit it by accident).

Answer (score 0):

You can create **[watches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_Watches.html)** for such methods to show their results in debug menu all the time.

Or simply use **[Evaluate Expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Evaluating_Expressions.html)** to get the result once.